# Passing multiple dimensions to google analytics reporting API v4 with javaScript

Tags: javascript, google-analytics-api

How would I go about passing multiple dimensions when executing a Google Analytics Reporting API v4 Query. For example how would I pass ga:dimension7 in addition to ga:dimension5 in my dimensions?

```js
function queryReports() {
        gapi.client.request({
            path: '/v4/reports:batchGet',
            root: 'https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/',
            method: 'POST',
            body: {
                reportRequests: [
                    {
                        viewId: VIEW_ID,
                        dateRanges: [
                            {
                                startDate: '7daysAgo',
                                endDate: 'today'
                            }
                        ],
                        dimensions: [
                            {
                                name: 'ga:dimension5'
                            }
                        ],
                        metrics: [
                            {
                                expression: 'ga:totalEvents',
                                alias: 'orderNumber'
                            }
                        ],
                        filtersExpression: 'ga:eventCategory==xxx,ga:eventAction==xxx',
                        filtersExpression: 'ga:dimension5=~\^\\\[.*\\\]\$'
                    }
                ]
            }
        }).then(displayResults, console.error.bind(console));
    }
```

When I separate them with comma,then I have the error below:

[image: wrong message]

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

I have the answer below:

```js
POST https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet
{
  "reportRequests":[
  {
    ...
    "dimensions": [
    {
      "name":"ga:dimension3"
    },{
      "name":"ga:dimension5"
    }],
    ...
  }]
}
```

see details here [guide to migrate the Core Reporting API V3 to the Analytics Reporting API V4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/migration)

Answer (score 2):

```
sample_request = {
      'viewId': 'xxxxxxxxx',
      'dateRanges': {
          'startDate': datetime.strftime(datetime.now() - timedelta(days = 30),'%Y-%m-%d'),
          'endDate': datetime.strftime(datetime.now(),'%Y-%m-%d')
      },

      "dimensions": 
      [
        {"name": "ga:date"},
        {"name": "ga:userType"},
        {"name": "ga:sessionDurationBucket"}
      ],
      "metrics": 
      [
        {"expression": "ga:sessions"},
        {"expression": "ga:newUsers"},
        {"expression": "ga:bounces"}
      ],
    }
```

Easy to understand pattern here for calling multiple dimensions and metrics.
Replace 'ga:' with your choice of Dimensions and Metrics. Exclude date and time if ou want. It will show specific sessions occurring on that dates

Answer (score 0):

Your can use multiples dimencions like this

```
dimensions: "ga:date,ga:campaign"
```

Here share an example:

```
function getData() {
  const response = await jwt.authorize();
  const result = await google.analytics("v3").data.ga.get({
    auth: jwt,
    ids: "ga:" + view_id,
    "start-date": "2021-05-01",
    "end-date": "today",
    dimensions: "ga:date,ga:campaign",
    metrics: "ga:users",
    sort: "ga:campaign,ga:date",
  });

  console.dir(result);
};

getData();
```